# How do i fill SVG with color

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, svg

Can somebody help me with css and javascript?
I need to create a page with scroll animation.
https://meetlima.com/how-it-works.php?lang=en
The 1,2,3 must be filled with color.

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="een">
    <svg width="200" height="200" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
     <!-- Created with SVG-edit - http://svg-edit.googlecode.com/ -->
     <g>
      <title>Layer 1</title>
      <text
        stroke="#000000" transform="matrix(9.676384925842285,0,0,9.676384925842285,-1584.9315026253462,-1064.0772700458765) " 
      xml:space="preserve" 
      text-anchor="middle" 
      font-family="Fantasy" 
      font-size="24" 
      id="svg_1" 
      y="129.86676" 
      x="174.14887" 
      stroke-width="0" 
      fill="#bfbfbf">1</text>
     </g>
    </svg>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: attribute `fill` is supposed to change the font color of your 1,2 and 3

Comment: The svg need to change color when scrolling the webpage. grey => color...

Answer (score 0):

In fact on page you've shared as exapmle the svg numbers have transparent color.

Initially you see grey background of **div.how-it-works__step__bg__inner**.

On backface there is a **div.how-it-works__faker** which has fixed position and lowest z-index. Also has inner element **div.how-it-works__faker__inner** with blue background

And when you scrolling down you may see the part of **div.how-it-works__faker__inner** under svg image.

to make it more clear check this screen just to understand what would happens in case you set higher z-index for div.how-it-works__faker

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CIRZ2.png)